# Optimizing a macro

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I have the following macros:

```
Sub As_Of_Analysis_Sorting2()
    Dim lr As Long, lr2 As Long, r As Long
    Set Sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sice")
    Set Sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Copy")
    Sh1.Select

    Sh2.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Kr"
    Sh2.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Tr"

            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next r
    Sh2.Select
End Sub
```

Here i take 2 specific columns and print them out on another Sheet. The next one is:

```
Sub ImportData_Click()
    Dim objExcel2 As Object, arr As Variant

    Set objExcel2 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ' open the source workbook and select the source sheet
    With objExcel2.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Macro.xlsm")
        ' copy the source range to variant array
        arr = .Worksheets("Copy").Range("A:B").Value
        ' close the source workbook
        .Close savechanges:=False
    End With

    ' select current workbook and paste the values
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Aktuel").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr

    ' close the source application instance
    objExcel2.Quit
    Set objExcel2 = Nothing

    ActiveWorkbook.Save


End Sub
```

Here i open a new Workbook and from there i get the data from the previous workbook. I've saved myself a lot of time, but still i fell there is more to do. Do you think that is possible that i create a macro in the second Document which not only copies the data from the first one, but also refreshes the first Workbook, executes the first macro in the first Workbook so i can get the specific columns that i want? The new Macro in the second Document  should run with an activate button when the Document is opened.

Comment: _" create a macro in the second Document "_ -> do you mean that macro should run WHENEVER the "second" document is opened or it should run ONLY when called by some macro in the first document. Please add details

Comment: The new Macro in the second Document  should run with an activate button when the Document is opened. Thank you for the tip, edited!